# Delete all uppercase paragraphs using find/replace

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

I’m editing a Word document, extracted with OCR from a scanned pdf. The problem is that it kept all the headers from the original document. As the headers are all in uppercase letters, I’m looking for a way to delete all paragraphs containing only upper case letters, using find replace. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot that shows the problem? That would help create a better answer.

Answer (score -1):

Open the Find and Replace window:

- Find what: `<[A-Z]@>`
- Replace with: Leave empty
- Select Use wildcards

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score -1):

Word can use wildcards in the search if you set that option. Wildcards can then be used to find all uppercase words.

Steps:

1. Open Find and Replace (it's also called Advanced Find):
   [image]
2. In the Find and Replace dialog click the `More >>` button to see additional options.
3. Set the settings as follows to find uppercase words:
   [image]

The `<[A-Z]@>` in the `Find what:` field can be broken down as follows:

- `<` looks for a beginning of a word
- `[A-Z]` looks for uppercase  characters in the range `A` to `Z`
- `@` looks for the preceding thing (in this case uppercase characters in the range `A` to `Z`) occurring 1 times or more.
- `>` looks for the end of a word

Comment: This will findings also uppercase words, not only uppercase paragraphs.

Comment: Well, the OP didn't specify if that's a problem for them. Perhaps their text does not contain uppercase words, perhaps it does so I'm not sure a downvote is necessary.